# How do I escape a variable in both single and double quotes? PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML input being echoed out and I cannot figure out how to get the variable $coins inside the single and double quotes.

```
echo '<form action="action.php" method="post">

      <input type="number" max="{$coins}">';
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

```
echo "<form action=\"action.php\" method=\"post\">

      <input type=\"number\" max=\"{$coins}\">";
```

## Option 2

```
echo '<form action="action.php" method="post">

      <input type="number" max="'.$coins.'">';
```